# Return to specific UITableView Cell

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I have 2 views.

On the second I have a UITableview where I can choose the content to view in the first window.

When I return to the second view containing the UITableView, is there an easy way to return to the cell representing the content on the main page, rather than scrolling down to it?

I'm assuming if I know the record number of the array that created the UITableview, which is the same array that I'm populating the main page with, then I should just be able to jump to that index number on the UITableView.  I can't figure out how to get the index number of the current record.

Sorry this is such a convoluted question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood you question correctly, to update the currently selected row in the previous tableView, you can invoke a method via delegate and perform something like

```
-(void) updateSelectedRow:(NSInteger)row {
    NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:ip animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
}
```

Comment: Got me where I needed to be.  Thank you.